# Is there a way to forcibly boot on a USB bootable device on a Mac?

Tags: macos, imac, usb, startup, ssh

I got an old iMac 21.5" (mid 2010) which I don't know yet if the graphic card is dead or if it's overall dead so I thought it would make sens to create a bootable USB drive running the latest OS release supported for that iMac, which should be El Capitan. I did that, but as I can't see anything on the display, I was hoping there's a way to force it to boot to that USB drive, logging automatically so I can reach the machine via SSH at least. Thanks !

Comment: And yes I know the Option key, but I don't think I can really use it blindly, do I ?

Comment: To test your computer and see if it is a GPU issue, use Apple Diagnostics (reboot then hold "D") or boot Single-User mode. From there, you can try performing basic repairs because Single User Mode doesn't need a GPU. You need to use the Option key to boot from an external drive because the default startup disk seems unreachable. Try booting macOS Recovery (reboot then "Command + R"). Also, do you see an Apple logo?

Comment: Why not hook up an external monitor?  I’m assuming that the screen is blank but otherwise turns on.